# Make non-compact subspaces compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact topological space and let $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in \Delta}$ be a family of non-compact topological subspaces of $X$ such that $\cup_\alpha A_\alpha=X$ and $A_\alpha\cong A_\beta$ for all $\alpha,\beta\in \Delta$.

Is there an induced topological space $Y$ such that the correspondent subspaces $\{A'_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in \Delta}$ are compact in $Y$. In other words, is there anything one can do "like compactification" to $X$ or the subspaces to get compact subspaces?

Comment: Do you mean that $Y$ should be a subspace of $X$ for the induced topology? Probably

Comment: Yes I meant that.  I was thinking in adding/removing points to the space.

Comment: It is not all clear how $Y$ should be related to $X$ as a *set*. Do you mean $Y \supset X$ or something else? If this is answered, we can think about topologizing $Y$.